# Running tomcat from another connected pc

Tags: php, apache, tomcat

I want to test some pages on several machine.

I have tomcat running on one pc lets say PC1 and several pc are connected to PC1. I want other pc to load the one page from PC1. I have tried some alternatives but it is not working

Does anyone know about this??

Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful to know what URL you are using on PC1 to open the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try http://ipaddressofpc1 on PC2. You can find your ip address of PC1 by running the command ipconfig on windows and ifconfig on unix PC1.